# how to update openssl in cocos2dx?

Tags: android, openssl, cocos2d-x

I recently receive an email from google play to update my openssl version. Many others also receive same email and questions about that has been asked. I want to know how to update openssl I have update it in my mac by following this link http://javigon.com/2014/04/09/update-openssl-in-osx/

But My apk is still showing old version that is 1.0.1a while my mac version is 1.0.1j. Please let me know what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I find out the way.....

For details follow this link http://blog.cocos2d-x.org/2016/04/openssl-update/

Comment: link does not contain solution

Comment: I have edit my answer. Please have a look OR follow this link http://blog.cocos2d-x.org/2016/04/openssl-update/

Answer (score 1):

“Beginning July 11, 2016, Google Play started blocking new apps or updated apps that use older versions of OpenSSL. If you’re using a 3rd party library that bundles OpenSSL, you’ll need to upgrade it to a version that bundles OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher.

In Cocos2dx, they used curl that uses openssl, so you need to upgrade the version of ssl, to do that you have to change curl version in cocos2d, you can find the curl folder in cocos2d/external, try to download new version of curl and replace it with curl folder.

you can find latest curl version

https://www.bengigi.com/cocos2d-x-fix-for-openssl-problem/

Answer (score 0):

You could cross compile it for yourself, but it's not very easy to do the job, especially for cross compile for multiple platforms. Recently cocos2d-x has made a new scripting system to compile all the 3rd party libraries for all the supported platforms.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-src

After clone this library and install all the dependences, you could start to build all the 3rd party libraries for yourself.

eg. For cross compile for ios with arch armv7 and arm64. You could simply call:

```
cd build
./build.sh -p=ios --libs=openssl --arch=armv7,arm64 --mode=release
```

For cross compile for Android with arch armeabi and armeabi-v7a, you could call:

```
cd build
./build.sh -p=android --libs=openssl --arch=arm,armv7 --mode=release
```

The version of openssl could be find in the "contrib/src/openssl/rules.mak". Currently the openssl version is already 1.0.1j, so you don't need to do anything about the scripts.

If you want to upgrade the openssl version, you should read the README.md file in that repository.